# Traefik - Cannot use self sign certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, traefik

I want to use dockertraefik with self sign certificates but i´m getting this error:

> time="2017-12-19T15:08:34Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration
>   file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"  time="2017-12-19T15:08:34Z"
>   level=error msg="Error creating TLS config: tls: failed to find any
>   PEM data in certificate input"  time="2017-12-19T15:08:34Z"
>   level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: tls: failed to find any PEM
>   data in certificate input"

Docker:

```
docker run --name traefik --hostname traefik -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock traefik
```

Traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/home/user/traefik/ssl/ca1.crt"
      keyFile = "/home/user/traefik/ssl/ca1.key"
[web]
address = ":8080"
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "domain.pt"
watch = true
swarmmode = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confusing the path of certFile an keyFile in Traefik.toml. I needed to put a volume for the certificates in my traefik container pointing out to my host files and to the path of docker container, the one i put in Traefik.toml. So:

```
docker run -d --name traefik --hostname traefik -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v $PWD/ssl/:/home/user/traefik/ssl/ -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock traefik
```

Summing, i need to create a volume like this:

> -v LOCAL_PATH_OF_YOUR_CERTS:CERT_AND_KEY_PATH_OF_TRAEFIK.TOML

Comment: Thanks for following up on your issue and posting the solution.  Updoot for you!